# Create pivot table from Google App Maker datasource

Tags: pivot-table, spreadsheet, google-app-maker

I have exported data from Google App Maker(2) into spreadsheet. The problem is, I have to do pivot table manually in the exported sheet in order to get the table such as in no(3). Image(1) show the field that I have in the datasource.

**(1) Screenshot of what I have in my datasource**
[image: (1) Screenshot of what I have in my datasource]

**(2) Data exported from AppMaker into Spreadsheet**
[image: (2) Data exported from AppMaker into Spreadsheet]

**(3) Expected pivot table to be exported**
[image: (3) Expected pivot table to be exported]

Can anyone teach me how to query data from the existing datasource to produce another table such as in no(3) in Google App Maker directly, so that I just export that data directly to sheet and no need to do pivot manually after the data has been exported .. or is there anyway better than that anyone else know how to do it?

Comment: What is your goal? I mean do you just need to pivot the table and present data to end user (and you just referring Sheets as layout sample because you know how to do it there) OR you **really** need to pivot table in Sheets?

Comment: I can process the data by do pivot table in sheet after the data had been exported. But, my goal is to export processed data from datasource that I have to sheet directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather to go with some nice [charts](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/charts) to layout these stats... but if you want to go Sheets way you'll need to do some scripting with [Apps Script Sheets Advanced API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets#create_a_pivot_table).

```javascript
// server side code
function addPivotTable_(spreadsheetId, pivotSourceDataSheetId, destinationSheetId) {
  var requests = [{
    // Request object goes here
  }];

  var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, spreadsheetId);
}
```